# YA book with smiling girl on the cover with very long braid and an animal

Tags: story-identification, books

Alright, so this is a fantasy book (I am eighty-five percent positive). Honestly I wish I remember something from the book, but all I remember is the cover. I read it in 2007. 
The cover has a young girl on the cover who is surrounded by green. She has fair skin and brown hair that is in a ridiculously long braid. there may all be a small animal on the cover with her, I'm not entirely sure. She's smiling, but it's a soft smile.

The series is meant for young adults and is part of a series. If anyone at all could help that would be super! Thanks again!

---

Incorporating comments from OP:

> It was a drawn cover, natural book. She was wearing a green top. She was only visible from just below her shoulders and up. There were green vines surrounding her, but all I remember of the background is green. I got it from my Aunt and I have no clue when it was written, but it seemed fairly new. Fantasy. I couldn't see how long the braid was, but I remember that it was described as longer than usual. No, it is not Rapunzel, I am 100% positive I would remember Rapunzel. It's not anything like Rapunzel.

> After searching for a while longer, I remember that it is centered around the girl and she had a small animal with her, along with a bird. That's really all I remember. I contacted my Aunt about it, but I'm not sure she'll remember. It was part of a trilogy! The first book is as described and the second all I remember is that she was somewhere near the sea.

Comment: This sounds to be rather difficult, but do you recall if it was a picture, drawing, painting, ... ? Comic, manga, natural, ... ? Clothes? Surrounded by green (solid color, grass, leaves, forest, ...) ? Do you know if it was new in 2007 (where did you get it?) or if it could have been older as in 2000s, 1990s, ... ? Was the book thick, thin, etc? Was it fantasy or science-fiction? What is *"ridiculously long braid"*? Dow to her feet, along the ground, around the earth, to the moon ... ?

Comment: As it is "young adult" it is perhaps not Rapunzel in traditional sense, but is that what you mean by *ridiculously long braid*? http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_NMdhBDpOTaQ/TNfsp8oaWuI/AAAAAAAAAtw/NODYZIaF-BM/s1600/Rapunzel+to+post.jpg or the more long, but not *that* long ... http://d.gr-assets.com/books/1336631746l/13641748.jpg

Comment: HOLY SHIT. YES. THIS IS IT. OH MY GOD. OH MY GOD. BLESS YOUR SOUL. I HOPE YOU FIND 20 DOLLARS ON THE GROUND.

Comment: Ah, can't believe this. I considered mentioning *"The Land of Elyon"* both in second comment and after your comment, but did not as it is a children's book and the braid was not very long. My bad. I went against my own intuition.

Comment: @Bekah please click the check mark next to the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 13):

*The Dark Hills Divide* by Patrick Carman. *Land of Elyon* series.

[image]

---

*While the OP hasn't accepted this answer, they have responded to the original comment suggesting this book:*

> HOLY SHIT. YES. THIS IS IT. OH MY GOD. OH MY GOD. BLESS YOUR SOUL. I HOPE YOU FIND 20 DOLLARS ON THE GROUND.

> Also, my memory is shit because I could have sworn her braid was longer and the cover was different. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Bekah, if this was indeed the book you were looking for, would you mind checking the checkmark next to it, marking it as the accepted answer? You'll reward the answerer that way.